# How do I change my class data when ajax is successful?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring

I am currently working on a project with `spring`.

My problem is to check `Flug` and change the value of the `class`. Data changes properly when refreshed, but does not change when it is brought to the screen via `history.back()`.

How can I change my data?

```js
function get_push_list(pushdata) {

var listdata = pushdata.map(function(obj){

        var html = '<li onClick="linkDetail('+obj.push_seq +','+obj.seq_no +')">'
                + '<div class="timeline-wrapper">'

        if (obj.flug != "N" ) {
            html += '<label class="timeline-label">'+ obj.type +'</label>';
        } else {
            html += '<label class="timeline-label not-read" id="timeline'+ obj.seq_no +'" >'+ typedata +'</label>'
        }

        html += '<div class="timeline-title">'+ obj.title +'</div>'
        + '<div class="timeline-content">'+ obj.body +'</div>'
        + '<div class="timeline-time">'+ obj.reg_date +'</div>';

    return html;
});

$('#pushlist').append(listdata);

}
...
function linkDetail(push_seq_no,seq_no) {

    var timelineid = document.getElementById("timeline" +seq_no);

    var data = {};
    data.seq_no = seq_no;
    data.flug = "Y";


    $.ajax({
        url : "/update_status",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data: data,
        success : function(result) {
            if(result.resultCode == "S000"){
                timelineid.class = "timeline-label"
                location.href= '/NoticeDetail?' + push_seq_no
            } else {
                alert(result.resultCode,result.resultMsg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Ajax` Success method Remove

```
timelineid.class = "timeline-label"
```

And Add (This is for `add` a new class to your tag)

```
timelineid.classList.add('timeline-label');
```

This is for `remove` old class from your tag.

```
timelineid.classList.remove('Class name you want to remove');
```

Comment: Hi @Hrv  `dacNotice.js?ver=2:79 Uncaught TypeError: timelineid.removeClass is not a function`

Comment: @helpmesolution then just add  `timelineid.addClass('timeline-label');`

Comment: `dacNotice.js?ver=2:79 Uncaught TypeError: timelineid.addClass is not a function`

Comment: @helpmesolution you added jQuery script in head tag?

Comment: @helpmesolution please provide html code to us for `var timelineid = document.getElementById("timeline" +seq_no);` this.

Comment: I'm drawing the code in JavaScript. Look at my code again. @Hrv

Comment: `'<label class="timeline-label not-read" id="timeline'+ obj.seq_no +'" >'`

Comment: @helpmesolution okay sorry! my mistake. addClass() is jQuery function. i update my answer for javascript.

Comment: @helpmesolution now check the answer and try.